# Behaviour of Python dictionaries: fromkeys vs dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have been annoyed by this:

```
data = ["A:3", "X:-1", "X:2"]
pairs = [data[i].split(":") for i in range(len(data))]
```

Now the pairs are in a nested list, i.e.:

```
In[49]: pairs
Out[49]: [['A', '3'], ['X', '-1'], ['X', '2']]
```

Then let's create dictionaries with two methods, that are supposed to be equivalent:

```
dico1 = dict.fromkeys([pairs[i][0] for i in range(len(pairs))], [])
dico2 = {pairs[i][0]: [] for i in range(len(pairs))}
```

We have this now:

```
dico1
Out[50]: {'A': [], 'X': []}
dico2
Out[51]: {'A': [], 'X': []}
```

And then let's perform the same processing for both dicts:

```
for i in range(len(pairs)):
    dico1[pairs[i][0]].append(int(pairs[i][1]))
for i in range(len(pairs)):
    dico2[pairs[i][0]].append(int(pairs[i][1]))
```

Yet, I have this:

```
dico1
Out[54]: {'A': [3, -1, 2], 'X': [3, -1, 2]}
dico2
Out[55]: {'A': [3], 'X': [-1, 2]}
```

But why?

To me, the expected behaviour is `dico2`. Is the `fromkeys` method recommended? What happens behind the scenes with this method?

I guess there is a difference inside the memory but more information on this behaviour will be really appreciated.

Comment: Note that `input` is the name of a built-in function in Python and it is considered bad practice to name a variable the same, as it can lead to bugs and confusion. I've renamed the variable in your post.

Comment: `fromkeys` is a trap. Don't use it.